# Checkboxes always returning value of "true"

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I inherited this project, and am new to spring-boot. I can't seem to figure out why the value of my checkboxes are being returned as true in manCreateGroup, but in manGroupsRedir they are false, which is what I want.

These are the methods I am refering to:

```
@GetMapping("/gotoman")
    public String manGroupsRedir(Model model, RedirectAttributes redir, Authentication auth) {
        Group group = new Group();
        model.addAttribute("group", group);

        MyUserDetails userD = (MyUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        Long idNum = userD.getId();
        User currentUser = new User();
        currentUser = this.userRepository.findById(idNum).orElse(null);
        model.addAttribute("currentUser", currentUser);

        Company currentCompany=currentUser.getCompany();
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findByCompany(currentCompany);
        model.addAttribute("userlist", userList);

        //will contain users to be added to the group.  may use group.reviewees instead
        List<User> usersToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
        model.addAttribute("usersToAdd", usersToAdd);

        List<EvalTemplates> evaltemplates = this.evaluationRepository.findByCompany(currentCompany);
        model.addAttribute("evaltemplates", evaltemplates);

        Map<Integer, List<String>> syncmap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        model.addAttribute("syncmap", syncmap);
        
        
        //initializes all activities as Synchronous for a newly created group.
        //this is changed by the user upon creation.
//      boolean synctrue[] = new boolean[]{true, true, true, true};
//      boolean strueL1 = false;
//      boolean strueL2 = false;
//      boolean strueCR = false;
//      boolean strueFTF = false;
//      List<Boolean> synclist = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
//      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
//              synclist.add("sync")
//      }
//      model.addAttribute("strueL1", strueL1);
//      model.addAttribute("strueL2", strueL2);
//      model.addAttribute("strueCR", strueCR);
//      model.addAttribute("strueFTF", strueFTF);
        String[] levellist = new String[] {"Level 1", "Level 2", "Consistency Review", "Face to Face"};
        Evaluator eval1 = new Evaluator(currentUser, group,
                evalRoleRepository.findByNameAndCompany(levellist[0], currentUser.getCompany()), currentUser.getCompany());
        Evaluator eval2 = new Evaluator(currentUser, group,
                evalRoleRepository.findByNameAndCompany(levellist[1], currentUser.getCompany()), currentUser.getCompany());
        Evaluator eval3 = new Evaluator(currentUser, group,
                evalRoleRepository.findByNameAndCompany(levellist[2], currentUser.getCompany()), currentUser.getCompany());
        Evaluator eval4 = new Evaluator(currentUser, group,
                evalRoleRepository.findByNameAndCompany(levellist[3], currentUser.getCompany()), currentUser.getCompany());
        model.addAttribute("eval1", eval1);
        model.addAttribute("eval2", eval2);
        model.addAttribute("eval3", eval3);
        model.addAttribute("eval4", eval4);
        return "manageGroups";
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    
    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping("/testing")
    public Object manCreateGroup(Model model, @ModelAttribute("group") Group group, @ModelAttribute("eval1") Evaluator eval1, @ModelAttribute("eval2") Evaluator eval2, @ModelAttribute("eval3") Evaluator eval3, @ModelAttribute("eval4") Evaluator eval4, RedirectAttributes redir, Authentication auth) {
    
        User currentUser;
        Company currentCompany;



        MyUserDetails userD = (MyUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();

        Long idNum = userD.getId();

        currentUser = this.userRepository.findById(idNum).orElse(null);
        currentCompany = currentUser.getCompany();

        //ensure user has correct permissions
        if(!currentUser.getRole().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Evaluator_admin")) {
            RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/adminGroups", true);
            redir.addFlashAttribute("error", "invalid permissions on user "+currentUser.getName());
            log.error("invalid permissions on user "+currentUser.getName()+ " does not have permission to create a eval group or assign evaluator role.");
            return redirectView;
        }

        //test for duplicates of group name and year
        //groupRepository.findByGroupName(group.getGroupName());
        boolean duplicated = false;
        if (!(groupRepository.findGroupsByGroupNameAndYear(group.getGroupName(), group.getYear()).isEmpty())) {
             duplicated=true;
        }

        if(duplicated){
            RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/adminGroups", true);
            redir.addFlashAttribute("error", "duplicate name and year entered: " + group.getGroupName()
                    + ", " + group.getYear());
            log.error("duplicate name and year entered: " + group.getGroupName()
                    + ", " + group.getYear() + ", this group already exists..");
            return redirectView;
        }

        //group = new Group(currentCompany);
        //set group company to curr user company
        currentCompany = currentUser.getCompany();
        group.setCompany(currentCompany);

        //defaults
        long lastGroupNumber = groupRepository.count();
        int groupNumber = (int) lastGroupNumber + 1;
        int level = 0;
        int defaultTemplate = 0;
        EvalTemplates evalTemplate = evaluationRepository.findByCompany(currentCompany).get(defaultTemplate);

        //deleted redundant cast
        List<EvalRole> roles = evalRoleRepository.findByCompany(currentCompany);

        //Add default evaluator roles if list is empty
        if(roles.isEmpty()) {
            EvalRole level1 = new EvalRole("Level 1", level, currentCompany);
            EvalRole level2 = new EvalRole("Level 2", level++, currentCompany);
            EvalRole consistencyReview = new EvalRole("Consistency Review", level++, currentCompany);
            EvalRole faceToFace = new EvalRole("Face to face", level++, currentCompany);

            roles.add(level1);
            roles.add(level2);
            roles.add(consistencyReview);
            roles.add(faceToFace);
        }
        
        
        
        
        List<Evaluator> evaluatorlist = new ArrayList<Evaluator>();
        evaluatorlist.add(eval1);
        evaluatorlist.add(eval2);
        evaluatorlist.add(eval3);
        evaluatorlist.add(eval4);

        for (Evaluator eval : evaluatorlist) {
            
                log.info("sync check: " + eval.isSync());
            
            evaluatorRepository.save(eval);
        }
        
        //NEW sync list setting:
        
//      boolean sync1 = eval1.isSync();
//      boolean sync2 = eval2.isSync();
//      boolean sync3 = eval3.isSync();
//      boolean sync4 = eval4.isSync();
//      
        List<Boolean> synclist = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
//      model.addAttribute()
//      
//      eval1.setSync(sync1);
//      eval2.setSync(sync2);
//      eval3.setSync(sync3);
//      eval4.setSync(sync4);
        
        
        
        //OLD sync list setting:
        //boolean synctrue[] = new boolean[] {strueL1, strueL2, strueCR, strueFTF};
//      List<String> synclist = new ArrayList<String>();
//
//      for (int j = 0; j < synctrue.length; j++) {
//          if (synctrue[j]) {
//              synclist.add("Sync");
//          }
//          else if (!synctrue[j]){
//              synclist.add("Async");
//          }
//          else {
//              RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/adminGroups", true);
//              redir.addFlashAttribute("error", " in new group Sync layout");
//              log.error("error in new group Sync layout");
//              return redirectView;
//          }
//      }
//      String[] levellist = new String[] {"Level 1", "Level 2", "Consistency Review", "Face to Face"};
//      for (int k = 0; k < levellist.length; k++) {
//          Evaluator eval = new Evaluator(currentUser, group,
//                  evalRoleRepository.findByNameAndCompany(levellist[k], currentUser.getCompany()), currentUser.getCompany());
            //unnecessary?
//          int evallevel = eval.getLevel().getLevel();
//
//          if (synclist.get(k).equals("Sync")) {
//              eval.setSync(true);
//          }
//          else {
//              eval.setSync(false);
//          }
//
//
//          evaluatorlist.add(eval);
//          evaluatorRepository.save(eval);
//      }


        log.info("self eval:" + group.getSelfeval());
        group.setNumber(groupNumber);
        group.setEvalTemplates(evalTemplate);
        //group.setSelfeval(false);
//      group.setGroupName(name);

        try {
            groupRepository.save(group);
            evalRoleRepository.saveAll(roles);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/adminGroups", true);
            redir.addFlashAttribute("error", "There was an error saving the group. Please try again.");
            log.error("Error saving group: "+e.getMessage());
            return redirectView;
        }


        redir.addFlashAttribute("Group "+group.getGroupNumber()+" was successfully added.", true);
        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/adminGroups", true);
//      RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/adminGroups", true);
        if(group.getCompany() != null) {
            log.info("Added Group " + group.getGroupNumber() + " (ID:" + group.getId() + ") For Company " + group.getCompany().getCompanyName() + " (ID:" + group.getCompany().getId() + ")");
        } else {
            log.info("Added Group " + group.getGroupNumber() + " (ID:" + group.getId() + ") [No Company]");

        }
//      ArrayList<Long> idfront = new ArrayList<>();
//      idfront.add(group.getId());
//      return idfront;
        return redirectView;
    }
```

This is my form in the html doc:

```
<form th:action="@{/testing}" th:object="${group}" enctype="multipart/form-data"
          method="post">

        <!--    <form class="form-inline" th:action="@{/testing}" th:object="${group}" enctype="multipart/form-data"-->
        <!--          method="post">-->
        <div class="row">

            <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="groupName">Group Name</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{groupName}" class="form-control" id="groupName"
                       placeholder="Group Name">
            </div>

<!--            <div class="form-group col">-->
<!--                <label for="groupYear">Year</label>-->
<!--                <input type="number" min="1980" max="2030" th:field="*{year}" class="form-control"-->
<!--                       id="groupYear"-->
<!--                       placeholder="YYYY">-->
<!--            </div>-->

            <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="groupYear">Choose a Year:</label>
            <select class= "form-select" name="groupYear" type="number" id="groupYear" th:field="*{year}">
                <option value=2023>2023</option>
                <option value=2024>2024</option>
                <option value=2025>2025</option>
                <option value=2026>2026</option>
                <option value=2027>2027</option>
                <option value=2028>2028</option>
                <option value=2029>2029</option>
                <option value=2030>2030</option>
            </select>
            </div>


            <!--            unnecessary and should not be changed by user-->
            <!--            <label for="number">Group Number</label>-->
            <!--            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" th:placeholder="${group.groupNumber}" readonly>-->

<!--            should not be changed by admin, as admin appears to be tied to one company according to the database-->
<!--            <div class="form-group col">-->
<!--                <label for="groupType">Company</label>-->
<!--                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupType"-->
<!--                       th:placeholder="${currentUser.companyName}" readonly>-->
<!--            </div>-->

            <div class="form-group col">
                <div class="form-check ">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="reqselfeval">
                        Self Eval Required?
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="form-check-input" th:field="*{selfeval}" type="checkbox"
                           value="" id="reqselfeval">
                </div>

            </div>

            <!--            <label for="evalForm">Company</label>-->
            <!--            <input type="" class="form-control" id="evalForm" :placeholder="">-->
            <!--            <label>EvalForm:</label>-->
            <!--            <select th:field="${group.evalTemplates}">-->
            <!--                <option th:each="template : ${evaltemplates}" th:value="${template}" th:text="${template.name}" />-->
            <!--            </select>-->


        </div>
        <!--        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">-->
        <!--        </form>-->

        <div class="mt-5">
            <div class="reviewerperms d-flex">
                <div>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <caption style="caption-side: top">
                            <h5 style="color: #198754">Reviewer Permissions:</h5>
                        </caption>
                        <thead class="border-top-0">
                        <tr class="table ">
                            <th scope="col">
                                Level
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">
                                Sync
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">
                                Preview
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Level 1</td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-check-input" th:field="${eval1.sync}" type="checkbox">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-check-input" th:field="${eval1.preview}" type="checkbox"
                                       value="">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Level 2</td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-check-input" th:field="${eval2.sync}" type="checkbox">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-check-input" th:field="${eval2.preview}" type="checkbox"
                                       value="">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Consistency Review</td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-check-input" th:field="${eval3.sync}" type="checkbox">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-check-input" th:field="${eval3.preview}" type="checkbox"
                                       value="">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Face to face</td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-check-input" th:field="${eval4.sync}" type="checkbox"
                                      >
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-check-input" th:field="${eval4.preview}" type="checkbox"
                                       value="">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="submit" value="Create Group">
        </div>


    </form>
```

I know the code is rather lengthy, with many lines commented out, but I figured I'd just include it anyways.

I have tried assigning IDs to all of the checkboxes that are labeled evalx.sync, but I didn't expect that to fix it since Spring Boot assigns IDs itself.

I also removed the value tags inside each checkbox for evalx.sync